# Is there any arch-agnostic way of obtaining instruction pointer on SIGTRAP?

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix, ptrace

I'm looking for an arch-agnostic way to obtain the instruction pointer (AKA program counter) of the last attempted instruction (or one past it) on which SIGTRAP was generated, from the perspective of a `ptrace` tracer.

An arch-dependent way is to use `PTRACE_GETREGS` and pick e.g. `EIP` on i386, `RIP` on x86_64, `PC` on ARM etc..

I've tried using `siginfo.si_addr` as well as `siginfo.si_ptr` from `PTRACE_GETSIGINFO`-returned struct, but these values appear completely wrong (4 hex digits instead of 8, and not even similar to the true address), so they don't seem to be what I need.

In Linux I've also tried making use of 30th field of `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stat`, which the kernel fills in `fs/proc/array.c:do_task_stat()` with `KSTK_EIP(task)` (which, despite being named x86-centric, appears defined for many other architectures). But for some reason on my ARMv6 Linux 4.9.28+ (Raspbian 8) I get zeros for both program counter and stack pointer.

So, is there any arch-independent way of determining the current/next address defined by POSIX or at least available in Linux?

Comment: How are you setting up your signal handler?  [Are you using `sigaction()` and setting the `SA_SIGINFO` flag in the `sa_flags` structure member?](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)  If so, you may have found a bug.  POSIX mandates that the `si_addr` member refers to the faulting instruction.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_43  You should add more information, including your code, and system particulars such as hardware and exact OS.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm starting a new process, which calls `ptrace` with `PTRACE_TRACEME`, and then I wait for the first debug event in the parent using `waidpid`. The event is `SIGTRAP`. Your link only says that it's for `SIGILL` and `SIGFPE` that `si_addr` is the address of the faulting instruction, but doesn't say anything about SIGTRAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `/proc/[pid]/syscall`.

```
mark@ubuntu:~$ gdb python
...
...
... 
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff78ed573 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 

mark@ubuntu:~/$ ps aux | grep python
mark      77858  0.2  0.7  90216 37780 pts/2    S+   15:13   0:00 gdb python
mark      77860  0.0  0.1  38416  6424 pts/2    t    15:13   0:00 /usr/bin/python
```

(see that `77860` is traced - `t`)

```
mark@ubuntu:~/$ sudo cat /proc/77860/syscall
23 0x1 0x7fffffffd980 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x7ffff7fdb700 0x7fffffffd958 0x7ffff78ed573
```

`0x7fffffffd958` is `sp` and `0x7ffff78ed573` is the program counter.

I couldn't find any `ptrace` call that helps here.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

> ```
>    /proc/[pid]/syscall (since Linux 2.6.27)
>           This file exposes the system call number and argument regis‐
>           ters for the system call currently being executed by the
>           process, followed by the values of the stack pointer and pro‐
>           gram counter registers.  The values of all six argument regis‐
>           ters are exposed, although most system calls use fewer regis‐
>           ters.
>
>           If the process is blocked, but not in a system call, then the
>           file displays -1 in place of the system call number, followed
>           by just the values of the stack pointer and program counter.
>           If process is not blocked, then the file contains just the
>           string "running".
> ```

Comment: Indeed, I've checked, and this does appear to work at least on x86, x68_64 and ARM.